# Sort column in table by newly named column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below.

```
Category  |   Col1    |   Col2   |   Col3    |   Col3    |
---------------------------------------------------------
Cat            7           20         10           5
Dog            2           9          2            1
Beaver         1           3          0            2
```

`select Col1 as 'Colname1',Col2 as 'Colname2',Col3 as 'Colname3',Col4 as 'Colname4' from Table1`

How can I sort this table to `'Colname1'+'Colname2'+'Colname3'` asc if I use query as above to select?

I tried `select Col1 as 'Colname1',Col2 as 'Colname2',Col3 as 'Colname3',Col4 as 'Colname4' from Table1 order by Colname1+Colname2+Colname3 asc` but its not working.

But it work if I order it by only 1 column name: `select Col1 as 'Colname1',Col2 as 'Colname2',Col3 as 'Colname3',Col4 as 'Colname4' from Table1 order by Col1 asc`

Desired result :

```
Category  | Colname1 | Colname2 | Colname3 | Colname4 |
---------------------------------------------------------
Beaver         1         3          0         2
Dog            2         9          2         1
Cat            7         20         10        5
```

Comment: What is the error you get from your current query?

Comment: What are the datatypes for `col1,col2 and col3`

Comment: I made some mistake to my question,  `order by Colname1+Colname2+Colname3 asc`

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 All are int

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Current error is `Invalid column name 'Colname1' , Invalid column name 'Colname2' , Invalid column name 'Colname3'`

Comment: ahhh..use the column name directly instead of alias name in the order by and then it should work

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 What if I must use the alias. Is it possible to sort using alias?

Comment: Why must you use the alias?

Comment: There is no meaning doing so until you have some valid argument. If you insists you can use one level sub query to use the aliases in the order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note that SQL Server used square brackets for aliases rather than apostrophes.)

It doesn't appear you can use the aliases in further functions (e.g., adding) as I believe the aliases are assigned after the processing stage.

Therefore you need the original column names if you want to add them.

The examples below should work.

```
select Category, Col1 as [Colname1], Col2 as [Colname2],Col3 as [Colname3],Col4 as [Colname4]
from Table1 
order by Col1 + Col2 + Col3 + Col4
```

Alternatively,

```
WITH A AS
    (select Category, Col1 as [Colname1], Col2 as [Colname2],Col3 as [Colname3],Col4 as [Colname4]
    from Table1
    )
SELECT *
FROM A
order by ColName1 + Colname2 + Colname3 + Colname4
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3be73ae865918533facb36622ef4478e) with each try (including the fail).

(Edit: added 'category' to selects to show dog, beaver, cat)

Answer (score 0):

Try ordering by the original column names, indicated by prefacing with the table name/alias:

```
SELECT Col1 AS Colname1, Col2 AS Colname2, Col3 AS Colname3, Col4 AS Colname4
FROM Table1 t1
ORDER BY t1.Col1 + t1.Col2 + t1.Col3;
```